# compiler problem with solidity and truffle

Tags: compiler-errors, blockchain, solidity, truffle

So I'm trying to learn to build NF token, and I cloned a repo. It's supposed to work with truffle.
The thing is I have an error with the compiler, and I don't really understand.  Indeed what I know is that the solidity compiler have problems with different versions, hence working with truffle CLI that works better with different versions projects.

So I tried to change to "pragma solidity >0.5.8 <0.6.0;", I did sudo truffle compile, and still have the error.

The error message I got is:

[my typo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ErIX.png) `Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.4+commit.3f05b770.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version

I know that I need to find a good version of solidity and truffle, but I believe that my versions are okay :

`Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5) Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js) Node v14.16.0`

Comment: Change the compiler version in the truffle-config.js file to match the one your are using in your smart contract.

Comment: I changed the compiler version in truffle-config and also the version of solidity in migrations.sol to pragma solidity ^0.5.0 , I don't have error no more, only warnings ! thanks for your help, merci!

Comment: Great. Can you accept my answer plz. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the compiler version in the truffle-config.js file to match the one your are using in your smart contract

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes even after changing the compiler version in truffle config the error does not go away so instead of using the specific version like ^0.6.0 use >0.6.0